# Efeito xadrez em uma imagem usando o JavaFX

Tags: java, imagem, javafx, java-8

Estou criando uma função utilizando o JavaFX para que ela utilize duas imagens e o tamanho dos pixels e retorne uma terceira imagem contendo um efeito xadrez a partir das outras duas imagens.

Segue abaixo o código,

```
public Image xadrez(Image img1, Image img2, int tamanho) {
int larg = (int) img1.getWidth();
int alt = (int) img1.getHeight();

WritableImage imgRes = new WritableImage(larg, alt);
PixelReader pr = img1.getPixelReader();
PixelReader pr2 = img2.getPixelReader();
PixelWriter pw = imgRes.getPixelWriter();

for (int x = 0; x < larg; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < alt; y++) {
        if ( x % 2 == y % 2)
            pw.setArgb(x, y, pr.getArgb(x, y));
        else
            pw.setArgb(x, y, pr2.getArgb(x, y));
    }
} 
return imgRes;
```

}

O problema todo é que não estou conseguindo arrumar uma forma de colocar o tamanho dos pixels, o código acima retorna uma imagem com o efeito xadrez porém utilizando apenas 1 pixel de cada imagem por vez. O que eu gostaria de fazer era utilizar a variável tamanho para assim pegar um grupo maior de pixels, como por exemplo 10 pixels por vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer, assumindo que "tamanho" sirva para as duas dimensões de cada quadradinho do xadrez, é assim:

```
for (int x = 0; x < larg; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < alt; y++) {
        if ( (((x/tamanho) % 2 == 0) && ((y/tamanho) % 2 == 0)) || 
             (((x/tamanho) % 2 == 1) && ((y/tamanho) % 2 == 1)) )
            pw.setArgb(x, y, pr.getArgb(x, y));
        else
            pw.setArgb(x, y, pr2.getArgb(x, y));
    }
}
```

===========

(editado)
Outro jeito, menos claro, mas mais elegante:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < larg; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < alt; y++) {
            if ( ((x/tamanho) % 2 == (y/tamanho) % 2 ) ) 
                pw.setArgb(x, y, pr.getArgb(x, y));
            else
                pw.setArgb(x, y, pr2.getArgb(x, y));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou!!
Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Interessante este outro jeito, vou salvá-lo aqui também.